# Random number generator in haskell using recursion

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have the following exercise :

In many computer programs, we need a random number generator. The numbers produced by these generators
are not really random, but they appear to be random. This explains why these generators are sometimes
called pseudo-random generators. One of the simplest generators of this type is the so-called linear
congruential generator s. These generators produce a series of numbers X_i using the recurrence
X_i+1 = (a · X_i + c) mod m.
The values for the parameters a, c, and m must be chosen wisely. If you are interested in how to choose these values, then you may want to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator.

In this exercise, we choose X_0 = 2773639, a = 25214903917, c = 11, and m = 2^45.
Give a Haskell implementation of the infinite list random :: [Integer] that returns the infinite list of
random numbers generated by this set of parameters. The time complesxity of take n random should be
linear in n. The expression take 6 random should result in:
[2773639,25693544934790,35087648281,25863180521136,928172761339,19643099434218]

I'm new to Haskell and I'm not sure how to generate an infinite list and even what the parameters of this function should be. Moreover, the recursivity makes it even harder as I am not sure how to write the base case. So far I have tried this:

```
random :: Int -> [a]

random 0 = 2773639
random x = [x | x <- (25214903917 * random (x-1) + 11 ) `mod` (2^45)]
```

Which is obviously flawed, but I can't come up with something else, as I don't have enough experience in Haskell to even think about other possibilities. Thank you for your time!

Comment: For an infinite list, there is no base case. Due to Haskell's laziness, it will not evaluate the next item, if it does not need another item.

Comment: Hint: You want to write a function that returns all the random numbers where the parameter is the first random number in the list. Hint 2: That means it returns the first random number (the parameter), followed by all the random numbers starting from the second one (calculated based on the first one).

Comment: Hint: to generate an infinite list you can simply recurse in the tail. E.g. `f n = n : f (n+1)` will generate the infinite list of the numbers from `n` onwards. You could try to adapt this line to fit your needs.

Comment: Hint: `random (x -1)` is not the same as `X_{i-1}`.  You need access to the prior value, such as with an explicit recursive function or a zip.

Comment: Thank you, I was finally able to do it!

Comment: @Udar How were you able to do it? You should be able to answer your own question using the form below.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it with that code:

```
random :: [Integer] 

random = f 2773639 
       where f x = x : f((25214903917 * x + 11) `mod` (2^45))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is one option; a somewhat cleaner way is

```
random :: [Integer] 
random = iterate (\x -> (25214903917 * x + 11) `mod` 2^45) 2773639
```

or, using point-free style,

```
random = iterate ((`mod` 2^45) . (+11) . (25214903917*)) 2773639
```

I would remark that, since your congruence is only 45 bits, you don't need to use `Integer` here, `Int` (or, to be platform-safe, `Data.Int.Int64`) is enough and better because it's faster and hints at how roughly large the numbers actually are that come out.